# Alignment between thermal and color images

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, alignment, registration

I have an RGB color image and a corresponding thermal image, generated by the same thermal camera. I'd like to check if these two images are aligned. so my question is how can I know if these two images of the same size are aligned or co-registred? are there any metrics or measurements that allow that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Maybe you could share some matching and non-matching images? Not sure what you mean by checking if they are aligned - it it your camera? Do you control it? Do you expect someone to have moved it between shots or something?

Comment: yes it's my camera, it's a FLIR One Pro camera that can generate a color image and a thermal at the same time, and I want to check if these two images are co-registred or there's a gap between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question.  Matlab suggests you start w/ an [intensity-based approach](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/intensity-based-automatic-image-registration.html).  There are more suggestions [here](https://www.researchgate.net/post/Can_somebody_please_explain_the_basics_behind_Multimodal_Image_Registration_and_suggest_some_good_references_for_a_beginner2).  In general, not a "plug and chug" type problem.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll take a look at it.